# Can't Select Ubuntu partition on startup

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

So,I'm in a bit of an odd predicament. My motherboard got messed up in such a way that now the SATA ports don't work so  can't use my hard drive, so I've been using live Ubuntu USB drives and just trying to not turn off my computer.

I wanted to have a full install, so I made a partition and installed it on an external hard drive.

But whenever I select the hard drive in the boot menu, the computer freezes. I wondering if maybe it's because I have other partitions on the hard drive but I'm not sure.